# The value of a variable changes after it's line of code is run in C#?

Tags: c#, variables, matrix

I've met this problem a couple times befores. Here's an example code:

```
public void moveRight(int x, int y, int rows, int columns)
    {
        char[,] imatrix = GameInstance.vexedGame.getLastMatrix(); // <-- creating a variable and initializing it.
        char letter = imatrix[x, y]; // Doesn't matters
        char[,] oldMatrix = imatrix; // Creating a new var that is the same as the variable created before
        if (imatrix[x, (y + 1)] == '-')
        {
            //LINE 1
            GameInstance.vexedGame.setLastMatrix(oldMatrix); //Setting the var of this class to the old matrix (until here everything's fine)
            imatrix[x, (y + 1)] = letter;
            imatrix[x, y] = '-'; //Changing the matix
            //LINE 2
            GameInstance.vexedGame.setActualMatrix(imatriz); //Setting the actual matrix.
        }
    }
```

What happens is that when I put breakpoints in the whole thing, when I get to the //LINE 1, the value is saved with the copy of the matrix before the changes. After I make the changes in //LINE 2, not only the value of imatrix is changed but also the value of the first matrix changes, so the GameInstance.vexedGame.setLastMatrix changes. I don't really know why this happens, and if anybody could help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Look in your favorite C# programming book and read the chapter again that explains the difference between reference types and value types.  Arrays are reference types.

Comment: I didn't knew that, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

That's because its an array and arrays are reference type.

When you do

```
char[,] oldMatrix = imatrix;
```

this creates a shallow copy. i.e. the address in memory is passed to `oldmatrix`. Now they are two variables but pointing to same adress in memory. if you change first the second obviously has to change.

To avoid this use loop to copy each value from first to second or

do a deep copy.

Comment: And how can I resolve this? I need them to be in separate places of memory... oh wait, I think I have to use the = new char[rows, columns]; right?

Comment: How do I do a deep copy? With a for cicle?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to expand on the other answers here. To do a deep copy you would need to either manually iterate through the values and assign them in that fashion, or use a prebuilt method. Something that could work would be [Array.CopyTo();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copyto.aspx) now this comes with issues as its a one dimensional array copy but that can be worked around with some coding. A helpful slightly different helper function is [Array.Copy();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) which is meant for copying ranges of values.

The reason it is one dimensional is that there is no telling how jagged the data sizes are within the two dimensions. This therefore is highly dependent on the structure of that multidimensional array. So it falls on the developer to solve that problem unless you can post the structure, for assistance.

Comment: Thank you! I solved this by creating 2 for cicles that asign all the values from one matrix to the other and the logical error is gone. Thanks!